# Pandas - Append CSV file with incomplete columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file with three columns:
col1, col2, col3
I'm trying to append to this file a DataFrame containing only the col2

```
ds = {'col2':[20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(ds)
df.to_csv(csi_filepath,mode='a',index=False,header=False)
```

the result is:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | NaN | NaN |

I would expect:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | 20 | NaN |

Is it possible to achieve this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `reindex`

```
ds = {'col2':[20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(ds).reindex(columns = ['col1','col2','col3'])
df.to_csv(csi_filepath,mode='a',index=False,header=False)
```